# TableRow programmatically added does not display

Tags: android, layout

In my xml layout, I have

```
    <TableLayout
         android:id="@+id/gridview"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" >
    </TableLayout>
```

and in activity

```
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    /* Find Tablelayout defined in main.xml */
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    /* Create a new row to be added. */
    TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Create a Button to be the row-content. */
    Button b = new Button(this);
    b.setText("Dynamic Button");
    b.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    /* Add Button to row. */
    tr.addView(b);
    /* Add row to TableLayout. */
    tl.addView(tr,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

But the button and textview in the tablelayout does not display. Any idea why?

Comment: Did you try to use invalidate() ?

Comment: @biovamp I am not sure how it will help. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you use `LayoutParams` of `TableLayout` otherwise your `LayoutParams` will have no effect on `TableRow`, something like this:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or simply import only `TableLayout.LayoutParams` i.e

```
import android.widget.TableLayout.LayoutParams;
```

Answer (score 0):

try removing this:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
    tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```